# Does the interval of confidance can be counted into the two sample T-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I'm working on a quelity control misson and i'd like to valid a mesure method. So I want to use the F test to compare the variance then use the two sample t-Test to verify if the two means of these two samples are nearly the same.

But generally, the company will use the percentage of the tolerant interval (TI) to judge if the mesure tool is good or not. But according to the documents that I've read, I think it's alpha (significance level) who decides we are 'tolerant' or 'strict', and the TI is not usful in my case?

And besides, all the documents I've read, for the H0, we can only use 'not refuse'. So does that means that this method is less 'serious'?

If we can use TI in the t-Test please explain a little for me or I've some error in comprehension, please leave a comment. Thank you.